# IOError - decoder jpeg not available - even after libjpeg-dev n PIL installation

Tags: python, django, libjpeg, django-oscar

I get this error when I try to access products or catelogue

I have installed libjpeg-dev and then pil.

I'm running the django_oscar sandbox locally. what should I do ?

Please also specify what additional info should I add ??

```
IOError at /catalogue/

decoder jpeg not available

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8888/catalogue/
Django Version:     1.4.6
Exception Type:     IOError
Exception Value:    

decoder jpeg not available

Exception Location:     /home/vagrant/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in _getdecoder, line 385
Python Executable:  /home/vagrant/oscar/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/vagrant/projects/ecommerce/clone/django-oscar/sites/sandbox',
 '/home/vagrant/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/vagrant/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/vagrant/projects/ecommerce/clone/django-oscar',
 '/home/vagrant/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_treebeard-2.0b1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/vagrant/oscar/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/vagrant/oscar/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/vagrant/oscar/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/vagrant/oscar/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/vagrant/oscar/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/vagrant/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/vagrant/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
```

Comment: Have recompiled (i.e. reinstalled) PIL since installing `libjpeg-dev` in your vagrant box?

Comment: yes I have reinstalled it

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ubuntu, there is a lovely blog post by the Oscar author about exactly this :)

http://codeinthehole.com/writing/how-to-install-pil-on-64-bit-ubuntu-1204/